# How to save entire term lineage

Tags: views, nodes, 8, taxonomy-terms

I need to **save term lineage** in Drupal 8, not only the deepest term. I know there are modules like *Hierarchical select, Simple hierarchical select or Client-side hierarchical select* but these are not for Drupal 8, or not solves "save term lineage" functionality.

I need to get my "nodes" visible on both child term and parent term pages too. I know, I can use the "**Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)**" (under contextual filters) functionality in "views", but it slows the database queries very much. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Is there some reasonable solution?

Thank you!

EDIT: The hierarchy is very simple. Only two-tiered: **Country / City**.

Can someone help me to re-save my nodes with "lineage" structure? For example, using the **TermStorage** functions listed below?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your understanding of reasonable. Until *hierarchical select* or similar modules become available you could save the parent terms programmatically on node save - the code probably wouldn't exceed 30 lines or so, especially when you don't have many taxonomy fields where you want to do this.

You can access a term's parents with the following code utilizing [TermStorage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!src!TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadParents/8.2.x):

```
$parents = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($termId);
```

Then you only need to go recursively through the tree and grab all parents (if your terms can have more than one), get their ids and set them in the node you want to save.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have many (almost one million) "nodes" already created. I need to apply any solution to the finished database.

Comment: Would batch updating your existing nodes be an option? The modules you named wouldn't update nodes already in the db either from what I recall.

Comment: Batch updating is ok, but....I need some "final solutions". I am not a programmer.

Comment: Not sure I can help you in that case. Even if I wrote some generic code, you would need to updated it to your needs with the right node/field/taxonomy names + duplicate pieces to cover all fields you need changed. At this point there are no generic 'final solutions' available I am afraid.

Comment: Hierarchical select is "just" a widget for the user, it doesn't change how those terms are stored. Either you have to live with the slow queries or you have to normalize it as suggested here. The only other alternative I can think of is doing it through a search API index, with custom indexing. But that will require a bit of custom code too. Not everything can be done (in a performant way) without programming, you can always try to hire one for this task.

Comment: I can not find any solution.
Zuzuesque? Could you please write some generic code for me? I think I could edit it for my needs. If it's about money, please tell me.